# Pandas groupby with FIFO

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a security id, a transaction date and a quantity. Quantity can be positive (a buy) or negative (a sell). I want to go from this transactions dataframe to a holdings dataframe, which as a first pass looks like a simple groupby security_id and sum.

BUT the transaction date is relevant for buy transactions, because when a security is bought determines when it pays interest (1 year from buy date). This means that effectively each security has a multi index combination of security_id + transaction_date.

So in the following example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'security_id': [2,2,2,3,3,3,5,5,6], 'transaction_date': ['2015-11-20', '2016-04-01', '2016-11-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-05-01', '2016-03-01', '2015-11-20', '2016-06-01', '2015-02-01'], 'quantity': [20, 30, -40, 25, 35, -15, 50, -50, 35]})

In [28]: df1
Out[28]:
   quantity  security_id transaction_date
0        20            2       2015-11-20
1        30            2       2016-04-01
2       -40            2       2016-11-01
3        25            3       2015-02-01
4        35            3       2015-05-01
5       -15            3       2016-03-01
6        50            5       2015-11-20
7       -50            5       2016-06-01
8        35            6       2015-02-01
```

As you can see there are 4 securities here, covering every relevant case.

Security 2 has first a purchase of 20 securities, then 30 and then a sale of 40. So net holdings for this one should be (with First In First Out) 10 securities bought in 2016-04-01.

Security 3 has a purchase of 25, then 35, then a sale of 15, so net holdings are 10 on 2015-02-01 and 35 on 2015-05-01.

Security 5 has a purchase of 50 and then a sale of 50, so net holdings is 0 (it doesn't really matter if it is removed from the df or remains there with quantity=0).

Security 6 has no sales, so should remain unaffected.

Visually, the result I want would look like this:

```
   quantity  security_id transaction_date
0        10            2       2016-04-01
1        10            3       2015-02-01
2        35            3       2015-05-01
3        35            6       2015-02-01
```

I can add a "net holdings" column with a transform:

```
In [35]: df1['net_holdings'] = df1.groupby('security_id')['quantity'].transform('sum')

In [36]: df1
Out[36]:
   quantity  security_id transaction_date  net_holdings
0        20            2       2015-11-20            10
1        30            2       2016-04-01            10
2       -40            2       2016-11-01            10
3        25            3       2015-02-01            45
4        35            3       2015-05-01            45
5       -15            3       2016-03-01            45
6        50            5       2015-11-20             0
7       -50            5       2016-06-01             0
8        35            6       2015-02-01            35
```

And remove sales by filtering out negative rows

```
In [37]: df1 = df1[df1['quantity']>=0]
Out[37]:
   quantity  security_id transaction_date  net_holdings
0        20            2       2015-11-20            10
1        30            2       2016-04-01            10
3        25            3       2015-02-01            45
4        35            3       2015-05-01            45
6        50            5       2015-11-20             0
8        35            6       2015-02-01            35
```

And now I'm left with almost what I want, but still need to group securities 2 and 3, for 2 removing the one bought on 2015-11-20 and in the case of 3 allocating the net holdings in a FIFO method as 10 for the one bought in 2015-02-01 and 35 for the one bought in 2015-05-01.

I can sort of see how a bunch of nested if's and for loops would do the trick but am hoping a more elegant solution exists before going down that rabbithole. Any help is really welcome!

**edit**
So I solved it, but not in a real elegant way. I created a new dataframe that tracks the running sold amount for each security, and cycle through each row discounting this amount. works for every variation I have tested but it's pretty far from kosher. I'll happily accept performance-enhancing/cleaning up suggestions. this is the block of code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'security_id': [2,2,2,3,3,3,5,5,6], 'transaction_date': ['2015-11-20', '2016-04-01', '2016-11-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-05-01', '2016-03-01', '2015-11-20', '2016-06-01', '2015-02-01'], 'quantity': [20, 30, -40, 25, 35, -15, 50, -50, 35]})
df['q_sold'] = df.groupby('security_id')['quantity'].transform(lambda x: x[x<0].sum())
#filter out sales from quantity col
df = df[df['quantity']>=0]
df = df.copy()
#sort by transaction date + security_id
df.sort_values(['security_id', 'transaction_date'], inplace=True)
#separate df that tracks running amount sold
df_sales = df.groupby('security_id')['q_sold'].unique().apply(lambda x: x[0])

for idx, sec_id in enumerate(df['security_id']):
    df.loc[df.index[idx], 'net_holdings'] = (df.loc[df.index[idx], 'quantity']
                                        + df_sales[sec_id])
    df_sales[sec_id] = df_sales[sec_id] + df.loc[df.index[idx], 'quantity']
    if df_sales[sec_id]>=0:
        df_sales[sec_id] = 0
df = df[df['net_holdings']>=0]
df.drop(['quantity', 'q_sold'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'net_holdings': 'quantity'})

Out[14]:
   security_id transaction_date  quantity
1            2       2016-04-01      10.0
3            3       2015-02-01      10.0
4            3       2015-05-01      35.0
6            5       2015-11-20       0.0
8            6       2015-02-01      35.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below code should work for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = df1 = pd.DataFrame({'security_id': [2,2,2,3,3,3,5,5,6],
                         'transaction_date': ['2015-11-20', '2016-04-01', '2016-11-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-05-01',
                                              '2016-03-01', '2015-11-20', '2016-06-01', '2015-02-01'],
                         'quantity': [20, 30, -40, 25, 35, -15, 50, -50, 35]})

def FiFo(dfg):
    if dfg[dfg['CS'] < 0]['quantity'].count():
        subT = dfg[dfg['CS'] < 0]['CS'].iloc[-1]
        dfg['quantity'] = np.where((dfg['CS'] + subT) <= 0, 0, dfg['quantity'])
        dfg = dfg[dfg['quantity'] > 0]
        if (len(dfg) > 0):
            dfg['quantity'].iloc[0] = dfg['CS'].iloc[0] + subT
    return dfg

df['PN'] = np.where(df['quantity'] > 0, 'P', 'N')
df['CS'] = df.groupby(['security_id', 'PN'])['quantity'].cumsum()
dfR = df.groupby(['security_id'], as_index=False)\
    .apply(FiFo) \
    .drop(['CS', 'PN'], axis=1) \
    .reset_index(drop=True)

print(dfR[dfR['quantity'] > 0])
```

And this produces results as below:

```
   security_id transaction_date  quantity
0            2       2016-04-01        10
1            3       2015-02-01        10
2            3       2015-05-01        35
3            6       2015-02-01        35
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually ended up going in a complete different route, but I had never seen a function applied to a group so that's cool.